# How would one write "face up" (e.g. as an instruction on a copier)?

Tags: translation, technology

We are trying to solve [a minor mystery over at Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25215/3437): I found a multifunction printer/scanner/copier/faxer that had the following instruction label on it.

[image: instructions on a multifunction printer/scanner/copier/faxer device]

Curiously, the last two lines are *both* in Japanese. The first one, 原稿面上向き *genkou-men ue-muki*, means something like "document face-up"; and the second one, 送信面上向き *soushin-men ue-muki*, means something like "the side you want to send face-up".

[User Earthliŋ's suspicion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/#comment54625_25215) is that one of these lines was supposed to be in Chinese, [perhaps as 原稿面向上](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/#comment54680_25215). From the perspective of the device manufacturer, that certainly seems reasonable.

On a linguistic basis, though, does that seem plausible? Does either of the two Japanese lines resemble what a Chinese device would use to indicate "face up"?

(Note: my knowledge of Chinese is virtually nil.)

Comment: "On a linguistic basis, though, does that seem plausible? Does either of the two Japanese lines resemble what a Chinese device would use to indicate "face up"?": Maybe not _would use_ but _could use_, since obviously not too much attention has gone into the translation, so it's a bit of a stretch to assume the Chinese translation would be natural.

Answer (score 4):

"Face up" in Chinese is `面朝上`.

[image]

---

An example sentence:

Place your card face up on the table, please.

请把你的牌`面朝上`摊在桌子上。

---

面向上 is also OK.

[image]

---

From the Japanese alternatives, perhaps the first one would be more intelligible in Chinese, but with 上 at the end of the expression.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I want to point out 送信 in this context is not intelligible in Chinese (送信 in Chinese has only one meaning, it's a V-O phrase for 'sending/delivering a mail'), so 原稿面向上 is the only possible one that was meant to be Chinese.

Comment: Sure. 送信 is out of context here, but 面上向 would still make a Chinese speaker get the gist of this inscription.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct. In Chinese, we normally use 正面向上. 正面 refers to the side with useful content.

原稿面 and 送信面 are both 正面.